# Downcast: why: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer

Unlike other examples of this error message i already have a pointer to `A` and want to retrieve the actual child class.

This kind of arrangement is part of some C++ wrapped C code there `A` is some POD C structure (whatswhy no dynamic cast)  and `test` is some callback in C that calls C++ functionality and to retrieve the correct object the cast should be used.
But to prevent C++ user code messing the C-Baseclass i would like to have the inheritance `protected`.

MSVC does not complain about this but g++ does!?
Which one is correct from the standards point of view and why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// plain C structure
struct A{
    int i;
};

// some C++ Wrapper class
struct B: protected A{
  A* get() { return this; }
  void print(){cout << i << endl;}
};



extern "C" {
  // C callback that gives it this pointer
  void test(A* io_self){
     auto b2 = static_cast<B*>(io_self);
     b2->print();
  }
}    

int main()
{
   B b;
   test(b.get());
   return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
$g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘void test(A*)’:
main.cpp:21:43: error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’
          auto b2 = static_cast<B*>(io_self);
                                           ^
```

Comment: If you want to successfully cast from one type to another outside of those class' scopes, you should use `public` inheritence, instead of `protected` one

Comment: It is a valid question though it is not clear how existance of method `get()` prevents user code to mess with base.

Comment: Do you pass `test()` by name? Otherwise I think there is no need for extern "C" and it can be a static method of `B`

Comment: @Slava the `extern "C"` also forces the compiler to use C calling conventions and disable name mangeling for the function. if this would not be the case, the call of the function would screw up the stack since the C-Code would have a different idea about how to transfer parameter to the called function.

Comment: That's why I asked if you pass `test()` by name. If not then name mangling does not matter. As for calling convention that's compiler specific, on gcc Inever had any problems passing C++ functions to C routines, like pthread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From c++11 N3337 draft (a bit old but it's the one I have lying around) 5.2.9/11 (static_cast):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D,” where D is a class
>   derived (Clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from
>   “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10), cv2 is the same
>   cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, and B is
>   neither a virtual base class of D nor a base class of a virtual base
>   class of D.

In this case, since you use `protected` inheritance there is no valid standard conversion from `B` to `A` so your `static_cast` is illegal (g++ is correct to diagnose it).

In this case since you're providing a c++ wrapper around a C API I think the simplest approach is to just stick with public inheritance and have a small amount of trust that your users won't abuse the C API directly *if they've already consciously chosen to use your C++ API*

Answer (score 4):

If you use `protected` inheritance, only derived types can be aware of that inheritance. As far as `test` is concerned, there is no relation between `A` and `B`. Since a `static_cast` can't cast pointers between unrelated types, you would need to `reinterpret_cast` instead. Or you may be able to provide `B` with a static method to preform this conversion, since `B` is aware of the inheritance. For example :

```
// some C++ Wrapper class
struct B : protected A {
    A* get() { return this; }
    void print() { cout << i << endl; }
    static B* cast_to_b(A* io_self) { return static_cast<B*>(io_self); }
};


extern "C" {
// C callback that gives it this pointer
void test(A* io_self) {
    auto b2 = B::cast_to_b(io_self);
    b2->print();
}
}
```

Be sure that the object referred to by `A* io_self` is actually a `B` and not just a `A` or it's undefined behavior.

Are you sure `protected` is the right inheritance for you here? It seems like `private` inheritance might be clearer as there doesn't seem to be any intention of inheriting from `B`. You may also want to consider forgetting about inheritance and simply giving `B` a `A` member.

Comment: I doubt you can use `dynamic_cast` with POD

Comment: @Slava Yep, I missed that. Thank you for comment.

Comment: using an A-Member disables me to retreive the B-Pointer in the callback.

Comment: Though having those 2 methods just a convoluted way of making that inheritance public

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is also not wrong because it breaks the addresses because `B` also inherits from another class.

Comment: @Slava no, as stated, the `test` function is some callback, that gets called from C-Code and it retrieves the C++-Object and calls the appropriate member-function. From the rest of the C++ Code this C-Wrapping should be hidden and direct access to the C-Base class should be prohibited.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I did not mean `test()`, I mean with existance of `get()` and `cast_to_b()` it is pretty much the same as having public inheritance. Btw why not to make `test` a friend and eliminate those pesky functions?